# Javascript problem with asynchrony in my code

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, async-await

I want to repair my code, but I don't know how. I don't have experience with async await syntax and I suspect I should apply this here. I have a json file where I have a two objects. I have two functions. First is editing one object, second shows us a view of the objects. Here is my code:

```
Tournament.editTour('1593595909353', 'tenis', 'ww', 'des 3');

Tournament.displayFromJSON((tournaments) => {
    tournaments.map((tour) => {console.log(tour);
    })
});
```

My goal is to see edited Tournament immediately, not after the second run of code. So my code is editing, but when I display immediately I still see the old version of the object. I tried something like this:

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Tournament.editTour('1593595909353', 'tenis', 'ww', 'des 3');
}).then(Tournament.displayFromJSON((tournaments) => {
    tournaments.map((tour) => {console.log(tour);
    })
}))
```

But it still doesn't work.

How to change my code?

Thanks for a help. Best Regards!

Comment: can you provide the code of the Tournament object and it's functions. Maybe provide a git repo or a codesandbox/codepen

Comment: Here is a repository: https://github.com/Karollo9921/helpWithCode